# Javascript regex: is there a way to retrieve a string within a string with a prefix and a suffix?

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to know if it was possible via regex to find a text within a string along with let's say 2 prefix chars and 2 suffix chars to the found string. For example if we have this:

```
let longText = 'yo this is a foobar string man';
let textToFind = 'foobar';
// the result should be 'a foobar s'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the regex:

```js
console.log('yo this is a foobar string man'.match('.{2}foobar.{2}'));
```

Secondly, this is basic stuff ... i would recommend you to read some tutorials of basic regex syntax, and start experimenting. There are some nice online tools to help you along the way:

https://www.regextester.com

https://www.debuggex.com

Also, besides the fact that nobody can read and understand its own regexes the next day, its a tool worth learning ;)

Comment: Great answer! this should be the best answer because of the prefix and suffix length customization it will be more flexible. Also thanks for the links !

Answer (score 4):

Simply construct the regexp using the `RegExp` constructor and using `String#match` to get the desired match:

```js
let longText = 'yo this is a foobar string man';
let textToFind = 'foobar';
let regex = new RegExp(`. ${textToFind} .`);

console.log(longText.match(regex)[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer is right but if he wants any suffix and prefix characters yours won't work because you validate for any character followed by a space character.

Comment: @Deathshadow -- It will be too broad to incorporate all the suggestions. OP wants to find the match with a prefix and suffix, which my code does. Even if it doesn't suit 100% to OP's requirements, it yet guides OP in the right direction. OP is free to customize this solution as per the needs.

Comment: Yes that is true just wanted to say it :)